# Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed (in function and out)

Tags: powershell

There is some annoying question, that was answered a thousand times... but

It still pissing me off

Here is the $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value

---

PSVersion                      5.1.17763.3770
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.3770
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

here is my code

```
$header = @{Authorization="Bearer xxx"}
Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri https://mm.xxx.ru/api/v4/channels/of35if5gftgapfe61eyenw5111/members -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8" -Headers $header
```

and it's works perfectly

but, if this code was moved inside function like:

```
function GetDCMemders {
$header = @{Authorization="Bearer xxx"}
$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri https://mm.xxx.ru/api/v4/channels/of35if5gftgapfe61eyenw5111/members -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8" -Headers $header
$ids = ($result.content |convertfrom-json).user_id |convertto-json
$result = invoke-webrequest -method POST -uri  https://mm.xxx.ru/api/v4/users/ids -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8" -headers $header -body $ids
$users = ($result.content |ConvertFrom-Json).username |?{$_ -like "rua*"}
return $users
}
```

Always got ERROR

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At users.ps1:7 char:11
+ $result = Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri https://mm.xxx.ru ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

And I was trying to add this

```
$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols
```

and this

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
```

and even this

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

it's always the same result...

looks like it's about runspace or environment... some rocket science for me
guess it's depends on visibility area of code and function ?

Debug says:

```
Status         : SendFailure
Response       : 
Message        : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Data           : {}
InnerException : System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidOperationException: There is no Runspace available to run scripts in this thread. You can provide one in the DefaultRunspace property of the System.Mana
                 gement.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace type. The script block you attempted to invoke was: $true
                    at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                    at System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                    at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
TargetSite     : System.Net.WebResponse GetResponse(System.Net.WebRequest)
StackTrace     :    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.GetResponse(WebRequest request)
                    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
HelpLink       : 
Source         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility
HResult        : -2146233079
```

Comment: Looks like it is a bug and won't be fixed until 2024.  See : https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11658